# cross_val_score returns list of nan

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to create a model to predict the probability for an object to break in a specific year. I have information for different properties of different of these objects, such the year when they were created and broken (if so), a categorical property and two continous property (which when histogram is plotted, values for one continous are normal distributed and for the other only a few values possible).

Now to create this model first I remove nan from my dataframe, then I convert the categorical into different columns (e.g. pandas dummy, 1 column per label with 1 or 0), and then for each year I calculate how many objects broke, and divide per objects alive/broken that year to know the probability of the object to be broken along time. Finally, I create a dataset where I present per each year, all the objects and the probability to be broken for that year, e.g.:

```
year     object   year_broken  prop_1  prop_2  prop_3 ...  prob_broken
1990     ID0001     1990          20      1       0             0.40
1990     ID0002     1995          20      1       0             0.40
1990     ID0003     1992          25      0       1             0.40
1990     ID0004     1990          25      0       1             0.40
1990     ID0005     1991          22      1       0             0.40
           ...
1991     ID0002     1995          20      1       0             0.60
1991     ID0003     1992          25      0       1             0.60
1991     ID0005     1991          22      1       0             0.60
1991     ID0006     1991          22      1       0             0.60
1991     ID0007     1991          25      1       0             0.60
            ....
```

Is this aproach the best I can follow? I then want to apply a RepeatedKFold with a LinearRegression to obtain the model following:

```
# evaluate a model with a given number of repeats
def evaluate_model(X, y, repeats):
    # prepare the cross-validation procedure
    cv = RepeatedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=repeats, random_state=1)
    # create model
    model = LinearRegression()
    # evaluate model
    scores = cross_val_score(model, X, y, scoring='accuracy', cv=cv, n_jobs=-1)
    return scores

# configurations to test
repeats = range(1,16)
results = list()
for r in repeats:
    # evaluate using a given number of repeats
    scores = evaluate_model(df[['installed_year', 'dummy_cat', 'continous_prop', 'continous_prop2', 'year']], df['prob_broken'], r)
    print(scores)
    # summarize
    print('>%d mean=%.4f se=%.3f' % (r, mean(scores), sem(scores)))
    # store
    results.append(scores)
```

However I'm obtaining nans for every score. What should I do? Should I follow a different approach? Why do I have nan?

Comment: The first step in debugging this should be to try just `model.fit(X, y)`. You'll get a much more useful traceback for the error involved. Depending on how explicit that is, you may need to (and in general always should) provide some minimal dataset that replicates your problem. Finally, the rest of your question regards the modeling process rather than programming, and so is off topic here; try datascience.stackexchange.com or stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Actually model.fit works fine, although it returns a score of 0.13, which is not grate. Ok I have asked in another forum.

Comment: You are using a classification metric (`'accuracy'`) on a regression task.

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks! PS. If anyone need the metrics: See table in 3.3.1.1 https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html